# Find longest UTF-8 sequence without breaking multi-byte sequences

Tags: c++, algorithm, utf-8

I need to truncate a UTF-8 encoded string to be no longer than a predefined size in bytes. The particular protocol also requires, that the truncated string still forms a valid UTF-8 encoding, i.e. no multi-byte sequences must be split.

Given the [structure of the UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), I could just move forward, counting the encoded size of each code point, until I hit the maximum byte count. O(n) isn't very appealing, though. Is there an algorithm, that completes faster, ideally in (amortized) O(1) time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2019-06-24:** *After a night's sleep, the problem appears to be far easier than my first attempt made it look. I've left the previous answer below for historic reasons.*

The UTF-8 encoding is [self-synchronizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-synchronizing_code). This makes it possible to determine, whether an arbitrarily chosen code unit in a symbol stream is the beginning of a code sequence. A UTF-8 sequence can be split to the left of the beginning of a code sequence.

The beginning of a code sequence is either an ASCII character (`0xxxxxxxb`), or a leading byte (`11xxxxxxb`) in a multi-byte sequence. Trailing bytes follow the pattern `10xxxxxxb`. The beginning of a UTF-8 encoding satisfies the condition `(code_unit & 0b11000000) != 0b10000000`, in other words: It's not a trailing byte.

The longest UTF-8 sequence no longer than a requested byte count can be determined in constant time (O(1)) by applying the following algorithm:

1. If the input is no longer than the requested byte count return the actual byte count.
2. Otherwise, loop towards the beginning (starting one code unit past the requested byte count), until we find the beginning of a sequence. Return the byte count towards the left the beginning of the sequence.

Put in code:

```
#include <string_view>

size_t find_max_utf8_length(std::string_view sv, size_t max_byte_count)
{
    // 1. Input no longer than max byte count
    if (sv.size() <= max_byte_count)
    {
        return sv.size();
    }

    // 2. Input longer than max byte count
    while ((sv[max_byte_count] & 0b11000000) == 0b10000000)
    {
        --max_byte_count;
    }
    return max_byte_count;
}
```

This [test code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DJAlhkFuU7uPilfH)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

    std::cout << "max size output\n=== ==== ======" << std::endl;

    auto test{u8"€«test»"sv};
    for (size_t count{0}; count <= test.size(); ++count)
    {
        auto byte_count{find_max_utf8_length(test, count)};
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill(' ') << count
                  << std::setw(5) << std::setfill(' ') << byte_count
                  << " " << std::string(begin(test), byte_count) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

produces the following output:

> ```
> max size output
> === ==== ======
>   0    0 
>   1    0 
>   2    0 
>   3    3 €
>   4    3 €
>   5    5 €«
>   6    6 €«t
>   7    7 €«te
>   8    8 €«tes
>   9    9 €«test
>  10    9 €«test
>  11   11 €«test»
> ```

This algorithm operates on the UTF-8 encoding alone. It does not attempt to process Unicode in any way. While it will always produce a valid UTF-8 encoding sequence, the encoded code points may not form a meaningful Unicode grapheme.

The algorithm completes in constant time. Irrespective of the input size, the final loop will spin at most 3 times, given the current limit of at most 4 bytes per UTF-8 encoding. The algorithm will continue to work and complete in constant time, in case the UTF-8 encoding is ever changed to allow for up to 5 or 6 bytes per encoded code point.

---

**Previous answer**

This can be done in O(1), by decomposing the problem into the following cases:

1. The input is no longer than the requested byte count. Simply return the input in this case.
2. The input is longer than the requested byte count. Find out the relative location within an encoding at index `max_byte_count - 1`:

   1. If this is an ASCII character (highest bit not set `0xxxxxxxb`), we are at a natural boundary, and can cut the string right after it.
   2. Otherwise, we are either at the start, middle, or tail of of a multi-byte sequence. To find out where, consider the following character. If it is an ASCII character (`0xxxxxxxb`) or the start of a multi-byte sequence (`11xxxxxxb`), we are at the tail of a multi-byte sequence, a natural boundary.
   3. Otherwise, we are either at the start or middle of a multi-byte sequence. Iterate towards the beginning of the string, until we find the start of a multi-byte encoding (`11xxxxxxb`). Cut the string before that character.

The following code calculates the length of the truncated string, given a maximum byte count. The input needs to form a valid UTF-8 encoding.

```cpp
#include <string_view>

size_t find_max_utf8_length(std::string_view sv, size_t max_byte_count)
{
    // 1. No longer than max byte count
    if (sv.size() <= max_byte_count)
    {
        return sv.size();
    }

    // 2. Longer than byte count
    auto c0{static_cast<unsigned char>(sv[max_byte_count - 1])};
    if ((c0 & 0b10000000) == 0)
    {
        // 2.1 ASCII
        return max_byte_count;
    }

    auto c1{static_cast<unsigned char>(sv[max_byte_count])};
    if (((c1 & 0b10000000) == 0) || ((c1 & 0b11000000) == 0b11000000))
    {
        // 2.2. At end of multi-byte sequence
        return max_byte_count;
    }

    // 2.3. At start or middle of multi-byte sequence
    unsigned char c{};
    do
    {
        --max_byte_count;
        c = static_cast<unsigned char>(sv[max_byte_count]);
    } while ((c & 0b11000000) != 0b11000000);
    return max_byte_count;
}
```

The following test code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

    std::cout << "max size output\n=== ==== ======" << std::endl;

    auto test{u8"€«test»"sv};
    for (size_t count{0}; count <= test.size(); ++count)
    {
        auto byte_count{find_max_utf8_length(test, count)};
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << std::setfill(' ') << count
                  << std::setw(5) << std::setfill(' ') << byte_count
                  << " " << std::string(begin(test), byte_count) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

produces [this output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WS9Go0lyBnSC6Noz):

> ```cpp
> max size output
> === ==== ======
>   0    0 
>   1    0 
>   2    0 
>   3    3 €
>   4    3 €
>   5    5 €«
>   6    6 €«t
>   7    7 €«te
>   8    8 €«tes
>   9    9 €«test
>  10    9 €«test
>  11   11 €«test»
> ```

Comment: @lig: I thought this were useful, too. So useful even, that I was convinced, that someone, somewhere *must* have written this before. I searched literally for days, and didn't find anything like this. With all the hype about UTF-8 being self-synchronizing, one would hope to *easily* find an implementation taking advantage of this property. Yet I found nothing. Good to know, that this appears to be useful to someone else, thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable: The reason you don't see this code much is because you generally don't need it. Splitting a string on an arbitrary code unit boundary (you must give me no more than X code units, but I need them to encode full codepoints) like that isn't terribly useful in terms of basic Unicode processing. You usually need to split strings on codepoint or grapheme-cluster boundaries, which has entirely different processing requirements. And outside of Unicode processing, dealing with UTF-8 text is generally done via copying it around.

Comment: @nic: I'd disagree with the notion, that this were not generally needed. Whenever you deal with a protocol, that packages units of information with a maximum packet size, it greatly simplifies processing, if you can establish encoding validity of individual packets. Unicode processing is challenging enough; adding transient decoding state to the mix certainly won't make your network client any simpler. You are right, though, I should add a note, that this implementation does nothing with respect to Unicode processing.

Comment: @IInspectable: Why would a protocol need to verify the validity of a UTF-8 sequence at the packet level? At the higher level when things get assembled, the check makes sense. But packet-level verification would be something like a CRC check for corruption, not a UTF-8 encoding check. A failure of UTF-8 encoding is not a packet or network transmission issue; it's a "sender did not know what to put in the packet" issue. So it should be handled outside of the networking layer. And if you do detect it at a packet level, it's not like the sender can *repair* it at the packet level.

Comment: @nic: Indeed, the protocol should not verify anything. It should simply mandate encoding validity. If it does, this Q&A explains, how to write a producer.

Comment: In practice, many protocols, TCP especially, must be interpreted as streams of bytes. The places where text is divided into packets is not useful in processing.

Comment: @tom: I was referring to *"protocol"* in its general meaning, not necessarily in context of networking. But even with networking, consider a TCP receiver, that will want to decode a UTF-8 encoded message. The UTF-8 decoder may require valid UTF-8 sequences to work on. You can't just throw whatever stream of bytes you just received at it.

Comment: We agree about TCP. It's hard for me to imagine the need you are addressing.   Perhaps you can add to your question. Where does knowing that you have a codepoint boundary get you if you are not also on a grapheme cluster boundary?

Comment: @tom: *"Where does knowing that you have a codepoint boundary get you"* - Imagine a UTF-8 decoder operating on chunked input. A decoder that requires valid UTF-8 sequences can decode the input in *any* order. A decoder that does not have this requirement introduces ordering constraints, whenever a UTF-8 sequence straddles packet boundaries.